# Rails fastest way to get table records count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a `user` table in `Postgresql` database, if run `User.count`, it takes `150ms` to get result. It is too too slow to us. Ideally, it shall take less than 10ms to return me the result. Is there any way to cache sql result in **model** level? Something like

```
def self.total_count
  User.count.cached # that's my imagination
end
```

Comment: This is more about Postgresql than Rails. The way Postgres provides ACID properties has many advantages, but its disadvantage is that a table scan is required to get a precise row count.  Other databases can return a count in very small constant time. Maintaining a single count in a different table will create a terrible performance bottleneck, though if insert and delete are rare, it may be okay. counter_cache is just a Rails implementation of the same thing. But to use it to maintain the size of an entire table would be weird.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion, there are several ways you could go about this -

1. You could have another table that stores the count of the total number of users by incrementing the count there when a user is added/deleted or at frequent time intervals.
2. If your table is extremely big and accuracy is not the most important thing, you also look into Postgres' [COUNT ESTIMATE](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate) query.

   `SELECT reltuples AS approximate_row_count FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'users';`

Comment: For my use case (4.1 million rows), the estimate was only off by 160 rows. So may be accurate enough for you. The downside of caching the count is that is can go out of sync and will make inserts and deletes slower.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into counter_cache. It will work great if your user belongs_to another model  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I looked it already. But now I want All records, not associated to another model

Comment: The time to get the sum of all the counters will be very fast